# ios autolayout stackview - how to put one view over another having same dimensions and coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, uistackview

first time I am using autolayout and stackview. I was creating one login screen where I want to put one imageview and over that imageview I want to put one textfield with no borders.But I am sticking while using stackview.As If I am giving vertical axis that time my imageview and textfield is coming vertically opposite or if horizontal axis then horizontally opposite.How do I resolve this, please suggest me some way.

Answer (score 0):

Solution nr1: TextFields actually have background property, so you can set your image there.

Nr2: If you really wanna stick with your ImageView, then you need set your TextField width and height equal to your ImageView and center it vertically and horizontally.

Nr3: You can select your ImageView and your TextField and join all edges in alignment menu (it's that second button on the bottom of storyboard).

Nr4: Some combination between 2 and 3.

In my personal opinion stakview sucks and is somewhat hard to work with...

Answer (score 0):

Give negative spacing value to achieve one on top of another.
Also make sure Alignment is Centre and Distribution is fill.
I used this to add a label on top of image view like this:

[image]